# Can I carry Whey protein powder to India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india

Is the following Protein powder allowed while traveling to India (New Delhi) ?

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000QSNYGI/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QSNYGI)

Comment: You shouldn't ask a duplicate question, edit the original instead

Comment: He did this because he was expressly suggested to split the powder from the original question into its own question.

Comment: @Liam Some one tells me to ask a new question and someone tells me to edit the same question. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am based in Bangalore, India and when I click on the link in your question, I see this:
[image]

I guess if Amazon is allowed to ship it to India, then you are allowed to carry it with you. If you have any concerns, then you can order it on Amazon and request delivery in India. BTW, this item is widely available in India, at least in the larger cities. I have seen this in multiple supermarkets here and it is also available at Indian online stores like [Amazon India](http://www.amazon.in/Optimum-Nutrition-100%25-Whey-Standard/dp/B000QSNYGI), [ebay India](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Optimum-Nutrition-100-Whey-Gold-Standard-5-lbs-Double-Rich-Chocolate-/261606591988), [SnapDeal](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/on-gold-standard-5-lb/1606480282) etc. Do note that it is going to be comparatively expensive to buy this in India.